# uWSGI stats using uwsgitop and socket showing JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, django, server, uwsgi, uwsgi-stats-server

I am not getting uwsgi stats using uwsgitop and socket. I have put uwsgi configuration for the stats with socket and when I tried to get the stat using the command:

```
uwsgitop /var/www/uwsgi/proj.socket
```

It's throwing the error

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I am using uwsgi ***version 2.0.17.1***.

Here is my uwsgi ini file

```
[uwsgi]

# Multi Thread Support
enable-threads = true

# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = /home/user/base-dir/proj-path/
# Django's wsgi file
module          = proj.wsgi
# the virtualenv (full path)
home            = /home/user/base-path/

# process-related settings
# master
master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 10

socket = /var/www/uwsgi/proj.socket
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket    = 666
# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
daemonize = /var/www/uwsgi/uwsgi.log
pidfile = /var/www/uwsgi/uwsgi_hub.pid
logto = /var/log/proj_uwsgi%n.log
uid = user
gid = user
http-auto-gzip = true

memory-report = True

py-tracebacker=/var/www/uwsgi/proj.socket

--stats /var/www/uwsgi/proj.socket
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue even after adding socket = /var/www/uwsgi/proj.socket
stats = /var/www/uwsgi/stats.socket it says ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded for uwsgitop", line 181, in main
    dd = json.loads(js)

Answer (score 5):

I think that you should have something like this in your config file:

```html
 socket = /var/www/uwsgi/proj.socket
stats = /var/www/uwsgi/stats.socket
```

And run uwsgitop on the stats socket, like so:

```html
uwsgitop /var/www/uwsgi/stats.socket
```

Comment: hi @Claudiu i even tried that but still, it wasn't working

Comment: And did you run uwsgitop for the stats socket? Something like this: uwsgitop /var/www/uwsgi/stats.socket